# angualrjs how to ignore status 400 after POST success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to ignore or bypass this error code `400` and just trigger a function when this error occurs?

I tried this : --

```
vm.createOrder = function () {
 var deferred = $q.defer(); // update
 orderService.createOrder()
    .then(function (response, status) {
       deferred.resolve(response); // update
       if(status == 400) {
          console.log('Should never happen but trigger a function anyway! ');
          localStorage.clear();
        }
        console.log('Successfully created an order: ', response.status);

    })
}
```

orderService: --

```
createOrder: function () {
            return $http({
                url:  'apiURL',
                method: 'POST'
            })
        }
```

but it doesn't even `console.log` the string in the `if(status)` condition or in the `success`, but the POST method does go through so its posting the data I want to post but it returns an error code of `400`.

**Edit fixed**

```
orderService.createOrder()
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('Successfully created an order: ', response.status);
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    console.log('Should never happen but trigger a function anyway! ');
                    localStorage.clear();
                    console.log(e);
                })
```

Comment: Is your `createOrder` function returning (and resolving) a Promise? If nothing in your `.then()` is firing, that'd be the first thing I'd check...

Comment: I updated the code, tried using `$q` defer but not sure if that's how you actually use it. If not, can yous how how?

Comment: added service code that returns `$http` request

Comment: decided to use `.catch()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your service should look like this.

```
createOrder: function () {
               return $http.post('SomeURL')
                     .then(function (response) {
                          return response.data;
                     },
                       function (response) {
                           return $q.reject(response);
                     });
                }
```

You should call it like this, rather than a try catch.

```
orderService.createOrder().then(function(response){
   //Successfull Call
},function(response){
  //Error on call
});
```

Comment: Return data in then function ?

Comment: Yes. It returns the data you requested, otherwise it hits $q.reject and comes back from the service as a fail.

Comment: Returns where ?

Comment: +1 to what @BurakAkyıldız said. I used `.catch()` instead, im only ignoring the error code for some testing.

Comment: Returns to where you called the service from. As you can see my 2nd code snippet. If it was successful it will hit the part i commented successful.... if it failed it will go to the part where i specified the error would be handled...